# XML Parsing & T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Given the following from an XML field in a table:

```
    <View>
      <Criminal xmlns="http://tempuri.org/crimes.xsd">
        <Person>
          <PersonID>1234</PersonID>
          <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
          <FirstName>KEVIN</FirstName>
        <Cases>
          <PersonID>1234</PersonID>
          <CaseNumber>12CASE34</CaseNumber>
        </Cases>
       </Person>
      </Criminal>
     </View>
```

How would I pull the Person/PersonID, LastName, Firstname info?  Same goes for the CaseNumber.

My next issue is similar to above but lets add a second namespace:

```
<MessageContent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Content>Content in here!!</Content>
   <Type>Empty</Type>
</MessageContent>
```

Notice I have 2 namespaces in there AND they also have ":xsi" and ":xsd" in there too.  I think those are referred to as schemas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlContent XML)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES(1, '<View>
      <Criminal xmlns="http://tempuri.org/crimes.xsd">
        <Person>
          <PersonID>1234</PersonID>
          <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
          <FirstName>KEVIN</FirstName>
        <Cases>
          <PersonID>1234</PersonID>
          <CaseNumber>12CASE34</CaseNumber>
        </Cases>
       </Person>
      </Criminal>
     </View>')

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://tempuri.org/crimes.xsd' AS ns)
    SELECT
        PersonID = XmlContent.value('(/View/ns:Criminal/ns:Person/ns:PersonID)[1]', 'int'),
        FirstName = XmlContent.value('(/View/ns:Criminal/ns:Person/ns:FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        LastName = XmlContent.value('(/View/ns:Criminal/ns:Person/ns:LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM @table
    WHERE ID = 1
```

Returns an output of:

[image]

And for your second part of the question: yes, you have two namespaces defined - but they're not being used at all - so you can basically just ignore them:

```
INSERT INTO @table VALUES(2, '<MessageContent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Content>Content in here!!</Content>
   <Type>Empty</Type>
</MessageContent>')

SELECT
    Content = XmlContent.value('(/MessageContent/Content)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Type = XmlContent.value('(/MessageContent/Type)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @table
WHERE ID = 2
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Marc,  This is great stuff!!!  I'm picking it apart as we speak.  Now maybe what little hair I have will start growing back!!
Thanks!!